# Why the RayCast never hit the object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DetectInteractable : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public float distanceToSee;
    public string objectHit;
    public bool interactableObject = false;
    public Transform parentToSearch;
    public static bool detected = false;
    public Scaling scaling;

    private RaycastHit whatObjectHit;
    private bool clickForDescription = false;
    private int layerMask = 1 << 8;
    private GameObject objectWasHit;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !scaling.scaleUp)
        {
            clickForDescription = true;

            if (whatObjectHit.collider != null)
                ExecuteActions(whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject);
        }

        Debug.DrawRay(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward * distanceToSee, Color.magenta);
        if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out whatObjectHit, distanceToSee, layerMask))
        {
            objectWasHit = whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject;
            detected = true;
            objectHit = whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject.name;
            interactableObject = true;
            print("Hit ! " + whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject.name);
        }
        else
        {
            detected = false;
            //clickForDescription = false;
            print("Not Hit !");
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteActions(GameObject go)
    {
        var ia = go.GetComponent<ItemAction>();
        ia.ItemMove();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (clickForDescription == true)
        {
            ProcessOnGUI(parentToSearch);
            clickForDescription = false;
        }
    }

    void ProcessOnGUI(Transform parent, int level = 0)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in parent)
        {
            if (child.GetComponent<ItemInformation>() != null)
            {
                ItemInformation iteminformation = child.GetComponent<ItemInformation>();
                if (child.name == objectHit)
                {
                    var centeredStyle = GUI.skin.GetStyle("Label");
                    centeredStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperCenter;
                    GUI.Box(new Rect(
                          Screen.width / 2 - 50 + 20 * level, // <== INDENTATION
                          Screen.height / 2 - 25, 100, 50),
                        iteminformation.description, centeredStyle);
                }
            }
            // Process next deeper level
            ProcessOnGUI(child, level + 1);
        }
    }

    public class ViewableObject : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string displayText;
        public bool isInteractable;
    }
}
```

It's never pass inside this line :

```
if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out whatObjectHit, distanceToSee, layerMask))
```

And the variable objectHit is all the time null

I can see that the magenta raycast hit the window in this case it's a window that it should hit. But using a breakpoint on the line :

```
objectWasHit = whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject;
```

It's never get there.

The window have a collider and the script ItemInformation is attached to it.
But the problem is that the raycast not really seems to hit it.

Screenshots :

The first the magenta raycast :

[image: Raycast]

And the window inspector settings :

[image: Window]

The problem is that the raycast hit first the NAVI object.
What is the NAVI object ? The NAVI is a child of the player(FPSController) .
The NAVI is part of the player in the game.

I think that's why I used layers.

The main goal is that the player will detect objects that are interactable and once an object was detected the NAVI will start rotating.
When the navi is rotating it's kind of indication that the object is interactable in the game.

You can see in this screenshot the NAVI in both scene window and game window.
This is what is suppose to be rotating when the player is hitting a interactable object : The script is attached to the player :

FPSController( Player )

[image: NAVI]

And this is the player inspector with the script attached to it :

[image: Player]

And since the NAVI is allways a bit in front of the player the raycast all the time is hitting and detecting the NAVI instead the other objects in the game.

Comment: What [layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) is the window on? What kind of `Collider` is attached to it?

Comment: @Ruzihm The window is on layer Default. And the collider that is attached ot it a box collider and Is Trigger is set to false.

Comment: Not `BoxCollider2D` right?

Comment: No it's box collider

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a screenshot showing the magenta raycast and the boxcollider?

Comment: Just a general hint: rather use a `public LayerMask layerMask;` and simply configure it in the Inspector. Then use `layermask.value` in the raycast.

Comment: Are you sure you want a BoxCollider there? I guess I would use a MeshCollider in order to keep it's form instead of using a bounding box

Comment: raycasts dont work well from inside a collider. Looks to me like your capsule collider contains the start point of the raycast

Comment: Ok I found the problem. Should I update my question ? Not yet a solution but found what the problem is.

Comment: Did you try the `LayerMask` thing from my comment? Are you sure you used the correct layermask? So basically back to Ruzihm's first comment...

Comment: Will try it now.

Comment: This is what I did : added public LayerMask layermask thyen in the raycast checking I changed it to layermask.value if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out whatObjectHit, distanceToSee, layermask.value))

Comment: Then in the Inspector added new layermask name Interactable and changed in the script in the inspector the layernask value to Interactable. Then on the window also set the layermask to Interactable. And now it seems to be working. Is that the right way ?

Comment: If it is working it is probably the right way ;)